# R intersection keep the same length

Tags: r

I'd like to do intersection by name and keep the same length as original vector. I want to fill those non-intersected entry to be "NT".

```
vector1: p7d_A1    p7d_A2     p7d_A3 
        "random"  "random"   "random"

vector2: p7d_A1   p7d_A2
         "hello"   "hi"

output: p7d_A1    p7d_A2     p7d_A3 
         "hello"    "hi"       "NT"
```

Comment: I don't understand your expected output. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "intersection by name"? Why does `output` have `"hello"` as the first element? What are the rules that determine which element is kept from which vector?

Comment: It first matches by name, and then use the element in vector2. If there is no match, fill in "NT"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setdiff` to get names of `vector2` which are not in `vector1` and assign it with `'NT'`.

```
vector1 <- c(p7d_A1 = 'random', p7d_A2 = 'random', p7d_A3 = 'random')
vector2 <- c(p7d_A1 = 'hello', p7d_A2 = 'hi')
vector2[setdiff(names(vector1), names(vector2))] <- 'NT'
vector2

# p7d_A1  p7d_A2  p7d_A3 
#"hello"    "hi"    "NT"
```